# How to investigate what makes my app so slow to start?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, performance

My 3.1.3 rails app takes quite a while to start up, and even running `rails console` seems to take longer than it reasonably should.  For example, with my app it's 50 seconds from `rails c` to the command prompt.  In a test fresh rails app (e.g. from `rails new`) it's about 5 seconds.

Needless to say, this is really annoying, particularly when trying to run tests, etc.

I've seen the links at https://stackoverflow.com/a/5652640/905282 but they're pretty involved; I was hoping for maybe something that would be at a higher level, like "oh yeah, here's how long each gem is taking up during startup".

Suggestions, or do I just need to dive into the details?

Comment: limit the number of gem you have. And check in your initializer if there are no long task

Comment: What Ruby version are you using? 1.9.3 [fixes a performance problem in 1.9.2](http://www.rubyinside.com/ruby-1-9-3-faster-loading-times-require-4927.html) with `require`.

Comment: @tadman - thanks.  I am on 1.9.2, will try 1.9.3.

Comment: @shingara - certainly I've considered reducing gems, but I think I need all that I currently have in my Gemfile (about 20).  I'm pretty sure I don't have any long-running code in any initializers.

Comment: Wow.  @tadman - huge difference.  Moving to 1.9.3, `rails c` now only takes about 10 seconds.  I can live with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ruby 1.9.3 [fixes a performance problem in 1.9.2](http://www.rubyinside.com/ruby-1-9-3-faster-loading-times-require-4927.html) when a large number of files have been loaded with `require`.

That post describes how the performance of including new files is **O(N)**, getting progressively slower the more files are already loaded. Since Rails loads in a *lot* of files, it is a serious drag on start-up time.